# Перевод содержимого файла в Base64, C

Tags: c, base64

Курсы языка С от университета Хельсинки. Есть ещё функция, преобразовывающая из Base64 обратно. Когда я подаю один текстовый файл в `to_base64` и в той функции расшифровываю его, то получаю то же самое, то есть вроде всё работает правильно, но вот что выдаёт сервер, когда я пытаюсь отправить:

> [M5.03.a] to_base64 for source file 'generated' -- Your file differs from reference at byte 1. You: '?' (00), reference: 'r' (72)

Ещё выдаёт такое:

> [M5.03.a] to_base64() for source file 'generated' should return 174. You returned 59.

С функцией дешифровки всё нормально. Притом, что каждый раз сообщения разные, но всё время этот файл  `'generated'`.

```
#include "base64.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"
/* The set of base64-encoded characters. You may use this table if you want.
* (The last character is not part of the actual base64 set, but used for
* padding). 
*/
const char *encoding = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";


/* Open file named <src_file> for reading, and convert it to Base64 format,
* which is written to file named <dst_file>.
* 
* Returns: number of bytes in <src_file>, or -1 if there was an error,
* for example if opening of <src_file> did not succeed.
*/
int to_base64(const char *dst_file, const char *src_file)
{
FILE *s = fopen(src_file, "r");
FILE *d = fopen(dst_file, "w");
if(!(s && d))
    return -1;
char c = 'a';
int n = 0, k = 0;
while(c != EOF) 
{
        unsigned char b;
        c = fgetc(s);
        if(c != EOF)
        {
            n++;
            b = c >> 2;
            fputc(encoding[(int)b], d);
            k++;
            b = c << 6;
            b >>=  2;
        }
        else 
        {
            fclose(s);
            fclose(d);                
            return n;
        }
        if(k == 64 && c != EOF)
        {
            fputc('\n', d);
            k = 0;
        }
        c = fgetc(s);
        if(c != EOF)
        {
            n++;
            b += (c >> 4);
            fputc(encoding[(int)b], d);
            k++;
            b = c << 4;
            b >>= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            fputc(encoding[(int)b], d);
            fputc('=', d);
            fputc('=', d);
            fclose(d);
            fclose(s);
            return n;
        }
        if(k == 64 && c != EOF)
        {
            fputc('\n', d);
            k = 0;
        }
        c = fgetc(s);
        if(c != EOF)
        {
            n++;
            b += (c >> 6);
            fputc(encoding[(int)b], d);
            k++;          
            b = c << 2;
            b = b >> 2;
            fputc(encoding[(int)b], d);
        }
        else
        {
            fputc(encoding[(int)b], d);
            k++;
            fputc('=', d);
            fclose(d);
            fclose(s);
            return n;
        }
        k++;
        if(k == 64 && c != EOF)
        {
            fputc('\n', d);
            k = 0;
        }
}
if(k % 4 != 0)
    while(k %4 != 0)
    {
        fputc('=', d);
        k++;
    }
fclose(d);
fclose(s);
return n;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? Найти ошибку в реализации `to_base64()`?

Comment: @avp, да, в ней

Comment: Ну, для начала чтобы работало `if(c != EOF)`, `c` все же должен быть `int`.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо большое!) Помогло!